# Spectrum colorpicker get color with transparency

Tags: jquery, html, css, color-picker

I use the jQuery plugin [Spectrum](http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/) for a color picker:

```
$('#backgroundColorPicker').spectrum({
    color: '#000',
    showAlpha: true,
    move: function(color){
        $('#result').css('background-color',color.toHexString());
    }
});
```

See this code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/UkmXM/1/.

As you can see I set `showAlpha` to `true` to enable a transparent background. However, I don't get a transparent background.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A hex string doesn't support transparency. Use `color.toRgbString()` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/UkmXM/2/

```
$('#backgroundColorPicker').spectrum({
    color: '#000',
    showAlpha: true,
    move: function(color){
        $('#result').css('background-color',color.toRgbString());
    }
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't know why this is getting downvoted and would like to see an explanation.

Comment: Your answer is clearly correct, so maybe someone downvoted you for accepting your own answer? If so, they didn't know that answering your own question and accepting the answer is encouraged here as a way to share just this kind of information.

Comment: There wasn't any other answer and I didn't get rep for it.

Comment: Right, that's why my guess is that someone thought (incorrectly), "what's that guy doing - giving himself some rep?" Anyway, don't let it get to you - keep on sharing tips like this!

Comment: @MichaelGeary oh, I didn't mean to critique you ;) we're on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in [the TinyColor docs](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor): `toHex8String`

Answer (score 0):

In this javascript library toHex8String() currently returns the alpha component of the RGBA before the RGB, E.G. a white semi transparent hex code which should be: #FFFFFF80 instead returns #80FFFFFF which is teal.

A fix has been suggested: https://github.com/seballot/spectrum/issues/31 but in the mean time you can get the transparent colour by extracting the alpha value independantly and appending it to the hex string like so:

`color.toHexString() + pad2(convertDecimalToHex(color._a)`